# How to use preg_grep to find urls

Tags: php, preg-grep

In my project i have mutiple .csv files with domain names like `1www.abc.com.csv`, `2www.abc.com.csv`,or  `1m.xyz.com.au.cs`v, `2m.blackburneinvest.com.au.csv` , `3m.blackburneinvest.com.au.csv`

I want to search the pattern `*.csv`(excluding number) in an array with preg_grep.

I tried this so far

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
$files = glob("*.csv");//gets list of all the .csv file names in dir
foreach ($files as $key => $value) 
{
    $pattern = preg_split("/(\d+)/", $value);//Spilts Number from rest file name
    $fl_array = preg_grep($pattern[1], $files);
}
print_r($fl_array);
?>
```

But with this i am getting an error saying

```
Warning:  preg_grep(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

How can i edit ?
Thanks

Comment: Try something like this: `$fl_array = preg_grep("/" . $pattern[1] . "/", $files);` Does that do the trick for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
preg_grep(sprintf('/%s/', preg_quote($pattern[1])), $files);
```

Answer (score 0):

String inside double quotes is being evaluated and `"\d"` after all became not you expect it is.

Either use single quotes:

```
preg_split('/(\d+)/' ...
```

or escape backslash in front of `d`:

```
preg_split("/(\\d+)/" ...
```